# Unable to create packages in eclipse 3.7 and 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, package

I have two versions of eclipse and am facing the same problem in both of them. In the `src` folder whenever I try to create a package as `abc.xyz` it takes it creates a folder structure directly under the project directory rather than source directory. So finally it looks like this:

```
MyProject
|--abc
   |--xyz
|--src
|--other folders
```

I check property for `abc` and `xyz` and they are showing as folders. Even if I try to create a class inside `xyz` it will show up at the top level as

```
MyProject
|--MyClass.java
|--abc
   |--xyz
|--src
|--other folders
```

Additionally MyClass.java will have no package declaration. I also checked that in property window `abc` is listed as a folder.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does the src folder appear as normal folder or source folder? Maybe it would be good if you append a screenshot so we can see how the icons look like.

Comment: @ViktorK. `type: folder` for src folder

Comment: the type is folder for both normal and source folders. if you do right click on src folder -> build path -> Use as source folder ... does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are in package explorer view in eclipse.  Click on src folder -> build path -> Use as source folder. To avoid this step, use Java Project as a wizard when creating new project in eclipse (Don't use plain project).